# Strange scroll behavior on IE11 in windows 10

Tags: html, css, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

[Check my Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt565.gif)

1.You can scroll horizontally by dragging.
2.You can click the scrollbar-track and scroll down.

Can anyone tell me what causes this?.
*A similar behavior can be seen with Edge.

I turned off the IE option scrolling smooth option and stopped the strange scroll behavior.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  min-width: 100px;
}
#content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
  
<div id="content">
  <table id="content-table">
    <tr><td>cell_1-1</td><td>cell_1-2</td><td>cell_1-3</td><td>cell_1-4</td><td>cell_1-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_2-1</td><td>cell_2-2</td><td>cell_2-3</td><td>cell_2-4</td><td>cell_2-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_3-1</td><td>cell_3-2</td><td>cell_3-3</td><td>cell_3-4</td><td>cell_3-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_4-1</td><td>cell_4-2</td><td>cell_4-3</td><td>cell_4-4</td><td>cell_4-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_5-1</td><td>cell_5-2</td><td>cell_5-3</td><td>cell_5-4</td><td>cell_5-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_6-1</td><td>cell_6-2</td><td>cell_6-3</td><td>cell_6-4</td><td>cell_6-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_7-1</td><td>cell_7-2</td><td>cell_7-3</td><td>cell_7-4</td><td>cell_7-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_8-1</td><td>cell_8-2</td><td>cell_8-3</td><td>cell_8-4</td><td>cell_8-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_9-1</td><td>cell_9-2</td><td>cell_9-3</td><td>cell_9-4</td><td>cell_9-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_10-1</td><td>cell_10-2</td><td>cell_10-3</td><td>cell_10-4</td><td>cell_10-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_11-1</td><td>cell_11-2</td><td>cell_11-3</td><td>cell_11-4</td><td>cell_11-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_12-1</td><td>cell_12-2</td><td>cell_12-3</td><td>cell_12-4</td><td>cell_12-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_13-1</td><td>cell_13-2</td><td>cell_13-3</td><td>cell_13-4</td><td>cell_13-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_14-1</td><td>cell_14-2</td><td>cell_14-3</td><td>cell_14-4</td><td>cell_14-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_15-1</td><td>cell_15-2</td><td>cell_15-3</td><td>cell_15-4</td><td>cell_15-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_16-1</td><td>cell_16-2</td><td>cell_16-3</td><td>cell_16-4</td><td>cell_16-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_17-1</td><td>cell_17-2</td><td>cell_17-3</td><td>cell_17-4</td><td>cell_17-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_18-1</td><td>cell_18-2</td><td>cell_18-3</td><td>cell_18-4</td><td>cell_18-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_19-1</td><td>cell_19-2</td><td>cell_19-3</td><td>cell_19-4</td><td>cell_19-5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>cell_20-1</td><td>cell_20-2</td><td>cell_20-3</td><td>cell_20-4</td><td>cell_20-5</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I turned off the IE option scrolling smooth option and stopped the strange scroll behavior.